# keyboard displaying in old layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, keyboard

I have following settings for my textfield

```
   _urlSearchTextFieldFirst.backgroundColor    = [UIColor clearColor];
_urlSearchTextFieldFirst.placeholder        = @"url";
_urlSearchTextFieldFirst.delegate           = self;
_urlSearchTextFieldFirst.keyboardType       = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
_urlSearchTextFieldFirst.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
_urlSearchTextFieldFirst.returnKeyType      = UIReturnKeyGo;
_urlSearchTextFieldFirst.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
_urlSearchTextFieldFirst.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

and the keyboard its displaying looks some old way some way zoomed.

[image: screenshot of iPhoneX]

Comment: Are you using the latest Xcode release?  Are you simulating phone or iPad?  I've seen this on released apps.  I'd like to know the answer too.

Comment: yes I am on Xcode 9.3.1, this iPhone X simulator

Comment: @BillDoughty but my application still support iOS 8.1

Comment: remove LaunchScreen and use LaunchScreen.storyboard

Comment: should I use Launchscreen.storyboard, currently I was using launch images

Comment: @PPL by removing this file, it resolved the top and bottom black bar for iPhone x but the keyboard board is still the same

Comment: If you want to support iPhoneX then you must us LaunchScreen.storyboard

Comment: @PPL I have added but the keyboard does not changed, as I said earlier the top and bottom black bar removed but I need to get rid of this keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You need to add iPhone X launch screen in asset folder .

Then Keyboard will work properly

And For layout

You need to use safe layout , Go to storyboard , Select ViewController to make safe layout which is compatible for iPhone X

[image: It will be applied for Xcode 9 and above]